# Weak referenced IBOutlet -- @property (assign)?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, iboutlet

Is it a valid approach to reference an `IBOutlet` weakly by defining a `@property` as `assign` in order to prevent a retain-loop? For example, I may want to tell the view what object is its controller; while there are workarounds using `nextResponder`, it's much easier to simply add an outlet to the view and assign the controller to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. The case you cite is a good example of when you *should* do it.

Comment: Also, It's usually also a great idea to make the outlet generic and use a protocol instead of 'MyViewController *'. Then if you name it  'delegate' it will be just like the system outlets from views back to controllers.